# Gold recovery under vacuum

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Can gold recovery with acid peroxide (ap) method be done under vacuum or left in sealed chamber, as opposed to placement in open air?

Comment: Use of peroxides would evolve oxygen, which would need room to expand.

Answer (score 2):

This process is typically done by extracting the gold in a mixture of something like 3 parts concentrated hydrochloric acid to one part 3% hydrogen peroxide. If this is roughly the procedure you are using, which is the common metehod posted all over the internet for recovering gold from used electronics, then the answer is an unambiguous ***none of the above***!

Unless you have experience and training for working with these chemicals in a laboratory setting, then you should not be doing this at all; it is simply not worth it.

Given that, the best answer your question is to use a fume hood, eye protection, gloves, lab coat, etc. The biggest danger you face, other than splashing the solution into your eyes, is inhaling the fumes. As this process produces toxic gases (chlorine as well as the fumes from the reagents themselves) you don't want to use a sealed container or a vacuum system that would just pump the gases out of your pump. You need an appropriate, certified fume hood for working with these materials. Relying on diffusion or wind in the "open air" is just incredibly dangerous and you could permanently damage your lungs in one unlucky breath.

Again, the answer is: ***none of the above, use a fume hood!***